# Paypal Express Checkout used on Sandbox, Security header is not valid, no error in API credential

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox, gwt-rpc, express-checkout

In my GWT-RPC project I want to use Paypal Express Checkout on Sandbox. I run my project on eclipse as GWT Super Dev Mode to test it.

Using the [paypal integration wizard](http://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/code.php) I've added the [paypalfunctions.java](http://pastebin.com/cm8TDAkT) class on my server side that permit calling PayPal API. On my server-side I have this AsyncCall, the log part is for debugging:

```
    /**

     * PayPal Operations
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public HashMap setCheckoutExpress(DatiPaypalCheckoutExpress paypal){
        paypalfunctions api=new paypalfunctions();
        HashMap response=api.CallMarkExpressCheckout(((Double) paypal.getTOT()).toString(), 
                "http://127.0.0.1:8888/MovieUniverse.html#order_confirmed",
                "http://127.0.0.1:8888/MovieUniverse.html#order_cancelled",
                "", "", "", "", "",
                "", "", "");
//      response=api.CallShortcutExpressCheckout("10.00",
//              "http://127.0.0.1:8888/MovieUniverse.html#order_confirmed",
//              "http://127.0.0.1:8888/MovieUniverse.html#order_cancelled");
        if(response!=null){
            GWT.log("Server: setCheckoutExpress() HashMap: "+response.toString());
        }else
            GWT.log("Server: setCheckoutExpress() HashMap: null");


        return response;
    }
```

the commented part, CallShortcutExpressCheckout works. But when I use the CallMarkExpressCheckout I receive in response

```
{L_LONGMESSAGE0=Security header is not valid, VERSION=93, BUILD=17329237, L_ERRORCODE0=10002, ACK=Failure, CORRELATIONID=9ce80c51dc8a5, TIMESTAMP=2015-07-09T16:25:14Z, L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error, L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Security error}
```

There aren't spaces in API credentials and the example method works so paypal endpoints are written right. 
I don't know how to solve it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes people confuse API USERNAME and API PASSWORD with regular paypal username and password of same paypal account and this also causes error 10002.

For example you might have provided API USERNAME but by mistake you provided regular password in SetExpressCheckout API call.

In sandbox mode API PASSWORD is given under "API Credentials" tab after you click "profile" link below "paypal-buyer@****.***" account record.

Answer (score 1):

That error does not happen unless the credentials are wrong in some way.  It could be the values themselves, or it could be that you're sending sandbox credentials to the live server or vice-verse.

If you're absolutely sure the values themselves are correct, make sure you're using the correct values with the correct endpoints.

Comment: I know but I'm using the sandbox credential in a sandbox environmnent but it doesn't work endpoint "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp", paypal URL "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=". my API credentiials are right and they are: gv_APIUserName = "movieuniverse_api1.gmail.com";
    gv_APIPassword = "E4T76Z68V4C38FS6";
    gv_APISignature ="AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AWKgxYWxptrQw.jokhnsrfl4nC6m"; So I don't get the problem

Comment: [Go here](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/samples/GetBalance.php) and you'll see I'm using your credentials with the GetBalance API.  It's working just fine on the sandbox, so your values are indeed correct.  There must be something about your code causing the values to get adjusted somehow.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I see. The problem is with paypalfunctions.java probably. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

At the end I didn't resolve in that way. I used the [paypal sdk merchant](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#merchant)
and to understand how use it, I used the great [API Explorer Paypal](https://devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/PayPalAPIs) that is very useful to understand which and how set objects of sdk. On the [how's to](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/) I've seen what sdk's object I need to set. I suggest this way to use API Paypal